# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when I am trying to build a const value to inject inside a Gallery. The `const` is build using a JSON

Here is the class where the issue happened:

```
class ClassDetails extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {anchorEl: null, 
            showJoin: false,
            classDetailsInfo: ''};
    }


    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({classDetailsInfo: ClassDataUseCase.getClassDetails()})
    }

      render() {

        const CLASS_PIC_LIST = this.state.classDetailsInfo.classpic
        const GALLERY = CLASS_PIC_LIST.map((pic) => ({
            src: pic,
            thumbnail: pic, //.replace("1280","_480"), // for example
            thumbnailWidth: 156,
            thumbnailHeight: 156
            }));
       ...
    }
}

export default ClassDetails;
```

The exact error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` and happened when doing `const GALLERY = CLASS_PIC_LIST.map((pic) => ({`

The `classDetailsInfo` is set using `ClassDataUseCase.getClassDetails()` defined as below:

```
class ClassDataUseCase {

    static getAllClasses() {
        return JSON.parse(ClassDetailsData.Classes)
    }
    static getClassDetails(id) {
        var jsonClasses = JSON.parse(ClassDetailsData.Classes);
        for(let k=0;k< jsonClasses.length;k++){
            if(jsonClasses[k].id===id){
              return jsonClasses[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the data are coming from the `ClassDetailsData` which is a JSON as defined below:

```
class ClassDetailsData {
    static Classes = [{
            "id": "c000001",
            "title": "Cook like a chef",
            "price": "5",
            "teacher": "Arthur Patrick",
            "teacherpic": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/03/08/55/portrait-657116_1280.jpg",
            "teacherid": "u0000000001",
            "desc": "Always want to learn to cook, that's the place you need to be",
            "bring": "Your fun , your motivation and you",
            "tags": [],
            "address": {
                "id":"",
                "Name": "Joel Robuchon",
                "address1": "3799 S Las vegas boulevard",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "las vegas",
                "county": "Clark",
                "zip": "89109",
                "state": "Nevada",
                "country": "United States"
            },
            "date": "2021/09/01",
            "time": "1:00PM",
            "duration": "2",
            "classpic": ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/16/23/10/spice-370114_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/13/18/47/spices-887348_1280.jpg", 
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/20/13/30/kitchen-731351_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/40/writing-828911_1280.jpg"],
            "reviews": [{
                "name": "Gabby Caldwell",
                "profilePic":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/03/08/55/portrait-657116_960_720.jpg",
                "rate": "5",
                "total_review": "13",
                "text": "Rachel was such a kind and knowledgeable guide. She took us to see some hidden coves that a lot of tourists probabaly miss. I’m keeping the map I made FOREVER!!!"
            }],
        }, 
        {........}
        ];
}

export default ClassDetailsData;
```

I do not understand why it's complaining. any idea ? thanks

Comment: What does `ClassDataUseCase.getClassDetails()` do to the initially empty string (`classDetailsInfo: ''`) defined in state? You should make your initial state object shape match what you expect it to be when populated with data, i.e. an array in this case so the initial render succeeds. Just remember, any state you set in `componentDidMount` will be available on the ***next*** render cycle.

Comment: Why id is missing while calling getClassDetails ?? and on the first go map will run on blank string.

Comment: You aren't providing an ID when you call getClassDetails in ComponentDidMount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be case when `this.state.classDetailsInfo.classpic` don't have the value. So `initialize` it with a default `[]` if it does not have any value.

You can do it like this:

```
const CLASS_PIC_LIST = this.state.classDetailsInfo.classpic || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `constructor` you are declaring your state with `classDetailsInfo` as a empty string, and a string doesn't have a `.map` method on it.

```
this.state = {anchorEl: null, 
            showJoin: false,
            classDetailsInfo: ''};
```

You need to declare the `classDetailsInfo` as an appropriate type for it not to break on the initial render.

```
this.state = {anchorEl: null, 
            showJoin: false,
            classDetailsInfo: {
              classpic: []
            }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your state you define `classDetailsInfo` as a string, that's the reason why you are getting that error

You should set initially it equal to an empty array `[]` to avoid unexpected behavior

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      classList: ''
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({classList: ["name", "data", "test"]});
  }
  
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.state.classList.map(cl => <span>{cl}</span>)}
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

You can look this simple example, If I change the value of state key `classList` to an `[]`  every thing work as expected. But now It reproduces the same error you get

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      classList: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({classList: ["name", "data", "test"]});
  }
  
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.state.classList.map(cl => <span>{cl}</span>)}
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In the second example after I initialize classList to an array it work.