# TypeError: LIST.map is not a function when parsing an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React is complaining about `TypeError: LIST.map is not a function` in my code below:

```
class MyCarousel extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        listOfClasses: []
  }
}

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({listOfClasses: this.props.list})
  }

    render() {
        const responsive = {
            desktop: {
              breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
              items: 4,
              slidesToSlide: 1 // optional, default to 1.
            },
            tablet: {
              breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 600 },
              items: 3,
              slidesToSlide: 1 // optional, default to 1.
            },
            mobile: {
              breakpoint: { max: 600, min: 0 },
              items: 1,
              slidesToSlide: 1 // optional, default to 1.
            }
          };
        

          const LIST = this.state.listOfClasses || [];

         
        return (

              <Carousel>
              {
                LIST.map((classitem) => 
                  <div>
                      <ClassCard title={classitem.title} desc={classitem.desc} pic={classitem.classpic[0]} id={classitem.id}></ClassCard>
                  </div>
                  )
              }
              </Carousel>
          
        );
    }
  
}

export default MyCarousel;
```

`listOfClasses` is coming from the props `list` sent by the code below:

```
class Discover extends React.Component {
    

    createSectionWithClasses = (title, classList) => {
        return <div> 
            <h2> {title} </h2>
            <MyCarousel list={classList} />
            </div>;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "discover-container">
                <h1> Discover a world of growth </h1>
                {Constants.categoryList.map((e) =>  { 
                                  return this.createSectionWithClasses(e.name, ClassDataUseCase.getAllClasses)                       
                              })}
            </div>);
    }
    
}
```

`classList` is an JSON Array get by `ClassDataUseCase.getAllClasses` which just a `JSON.parse(myjson)`

the `JSON.parse` is parsing a json array as below:

```
static getAllClasses() {
        return JSON.parse(ClassDetailsData.Classes)
    }
```

and `ClassDetailsData` is

```
class ClassDetailsData {
    static Classes = [{
            "id": "c000001",
            "title": "Cook like a chef",
            "price": "5",
            "teacher": "Arthur Patrick",
            "teacherpic": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/03/08/55/portrait-657116_1280.jpg",
            "teacherid": "u0000000001",
            "desc": "Always want to learn to cook, that's the place you need to be",
            "bring": "Your fun , your motivation and you",
            "tags": [],
            "address": {
                "id":"",
                "Name": "Joel Robuchon",
                "address1": "3799 S Las vegas boulevard",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "las vegas",
                "county": "Clark",
                "zip": "89109",
                "state": "Nevada",
                "country": "United States"
            },
            "date": "2021/09/01",
            "time": "1:00PM",
            "duration": "2",
            "classpic": ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/16/23/10/spice-370114_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/13/18/47/spices-887348_1280.jpg", 
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/20/13/30/kitchen-731351_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/40/writing-828911_1280.jpg"],
            "reviews": [{
                "name": "Gabby Caldwell",
                "profilePic":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/03/08/55/portrait-657116_960_720.jpg",
                "rate": "5",
                "total_review": "13",
                "text": "Rachel was such a kind and knowledgeable guide. She took us to see some hidden coves that a lot of tourists probabaly miss. I’m keeping the map I made FOREVER!!!"
            }],
        }, 
        {
            ....
        },
        {
           ....
        },
        {
           ....
        }, 
        {
...,
        },
        ]
}

export default ClassDetailsData;
```

Any idea why I have this error ?

thanks

Comment: can you try to print `classList` to see what it is ?

Comment: Already given one of your question answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949104/typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-when-parsing-json/62949266#62949266.

Comment: This error occurs when you call map on something that isn't an array, so `LIST` in this case is not an array, it could also be its null. If its a state or prop item, it may not have been set yet if it is populated from an API call. If its null you can use null propogation to prevent the map function being invoked until its set like this `LIST?.map(..` perhaps put a break point in and see what LIST is or as @Ahmed said console.log the value

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya it's not the same error and i did the init using []

Comment: If you face this type of error then try finding out why your variable does not have value. It should be an array. The error only comes when the value of the variable coming as undefined or other than the array. In your case the variable is LIST. As a solution, you can do it like (this.state.listOfClasses || []).map . But I would suggest check for listOfClasees value first, what is it coming?

Comment: With `  const LIST = this.state.listOfClasses ` are you sure that the listOfClasses is really an array? The way you can check when you log it arrays look like this `[...]` and objects like this `{...}`

Comment: @MaxCarroll I have added the information about what I extract - added the json in the desc

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya it's weird because it's just show me the function he runs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to console.log `this.props.list`.
`ClassDataUseCase.getAllClasses` seems like a function (by its name), maybe you just forgot to call it.
Change this:

```
... return this.createSectionWithClasses(e.name, ClassDataUseCase.getAllClasses)
```

to this:

```
... return this.createSectionWithClasses(e.name, ClassDataUseCase.getAllClasses())
```

Comment: So weird thing about this, is the it throw an error like `A cross-origin error was thrown. `

Comment: @Seb Seems like <ClassCard /> is now being rendered, I can see that it has `pic` prop and I guess it is an URL to the resource. Seems like browser isn't able to download it due to some cross-origiin error. Anyway the original issue seems to be solved.

Comment: So I found the issue.... wrong token in the json. The json was about 600 lines.... but one line had a bad char...